# How do I consolidate several invoices that at one point were backordered and then fulfilled in mysql

Tags: mysql

For example I have a 1 invoice with 1 that was in stock and 3 that weren't in stock. Later on, the 2 invoices were created for those backordered ones. I want to be able to consolidate all those invoices into one displaying that 3 that were shipped and 1 that is still on backorder.
mysql table is as follows:

| order_id | price | model | quantity | previous_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1788 | 1,200 | SBS | -1 | Null //backordered |
| 1788 | 1,200 | SSC | -1 | Null //backordered |
| 1788 | 1,200 | SAC | 1 | Null |
| 1788 | 1,200 | SBB | -1 | Null //backordered |

Second invoice

| order_id | price | model | quantity | previous_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1811 | 1,200 | SBB | 1 | 1788 |

Third invoice

| order_id | price | model | quantity | previous_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1865 | 1,200 | SSC | 1 | 1788 |

So as you can see previous_id tracks which was the original order for backordered items.

My mysql code is:

`SELECT * FROM order_product where order_id = 1788 or previous_id = 1788`
which displays all 6 rows but I want to be able to see 3 ordered and 1 backorder. Total should be showing 4 rows.

The final version should look like this:

| order_id | price | model | quantity | previous_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1788 | 1,200 | SBS | -1 | Null //backordered |
| 1788 | 1,200 | SSC | 1 | Null |
| 1788 | 1,200 | SAC | 1 | 1788 |
| 1788 | 1,200 | SBB | 1 | 1788 |

How do I achieve this?

Comment: there are 3 invoices all together. It could very well be 4 invoices but all the backordered invoices need to be consolidated into 1 main invoice.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql 8 you can do

The rownumber rn 1 has always the higher number in case of only -1, there is no order , if the number is positive it would be selected row

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders (
>   `order_id` INTEGER,
>   `price` VARCHAR(5),
>   `model` VARCHAR(3),
>   `quantity` INTEGER,
>   `previous_id` VARCHAR(18)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO orders
>   (`order_id`, `price`, `model`, `quantity`, `previous_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1788', '1,200', 'SBS', '-1', 'Null //backordered'),
>   ('1788', '1,200', 'SSC', '-1', 'Null //backordered'),
>   ('1788', '1,200', 'SAC', '1', 'Null'),
>   ('1788', '1,200', 'SBB', '-1', 'Null //backordered'),
>   ('1811', '1,200', 'SBB', '1', '1788'),
>   ('1865', '1,200', 'SSC', '1', '1788');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `order_id`, `price`, `model`, `quantity`, `previous_id`
> FROM
> (SELECT 
> `order_id`, `price`, `model`, `quantity`, `previous_id`
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY `model` ORDER BY `quantity` DESC) rn
> FROM orders
> WHERE `order_id` = '1788' OR `previous_id` = '1788') t1
> WHERE rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> order_id | price | model | quantity | previous_id       
> -------: | :---- | :---- | -------: | :-----------------
>     1788 | 1,200 | SAC   |        1 | Null              
>     1811 | 1,200 | SBB   |        1 | 1788              
>     1788 | 1,200 | SBS   |       -1 | Null //backordered
>     1865 | 1,200 | SSC   |        1 | 1788
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=655b978a768c1a270e05d7dbe8795604)*

For your new requirement

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders (
>   `order_id` INTEGER,
>   `price` VARCHAR(5),
>   `model` VARCHAR(3),
>   `quantity` INTEGER,
>   `previous_id` VARCHAR(18)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO orders
>   (`order_id`, `price`, `model`, `quantity`, `previous_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1788', '1,200', 'SBS', '-1', 'Null //backordered'),
>   ('1788', '1,200', 'SSC', '-1', 'Null //backordered'),
>   ('1788', '1,200', 'SAC', '1', 'Null'),
>   ('1788', '1,200', 'SBB', '-1', 'Null //backordered'),
>   ('1811', '1,200', 'SBB', '1', '1788'),
>   ('1812', '1,200', 'SBB', '1', '1788'),
>   ('1865', '1,200', 'SSC', '1', '17
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `order_id`, `price`, `model`, `quantity`, `previous_id`
> FROM
> (SELECT 
> `order_id`, `price`, `model`, `quantity`, `previous_id`
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY `model` ORDER BY `quantity` DESC) rn
> ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE `model` = o1.`model` AND `quantity` <> -1) mx
> FROM orders o1
> WHERE `order_id` = '1788' OR `previous_id` = '1788') t1
> WHERE rn <= IF(mx = 0 , 1,mx)
> ```
>
> ```
> order_id | price | model | quantity | previous_id       
> -------: | :---- | :---- | -------: | :-----------------
>     1788 | 1,200 | SAC   |        1 | Null              
>     1811 | 1,200 | SBB   |        1 | 1788              
>     1812 | 1,200 | SBB   |        1 | 1788              
>     1788 | 1,200 | SBS   |       -1 | Null //backordered
>     1865 | 1,200 | SSC   |        1 | 1788
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2175db6987e45dbbdb24162d1515583e)*

this is the last one

> ```
> CREATE TABLE order_product (
>   `order_id` INTEGER,
>   `price` VARCHAR(5),
>   `model` VARCHAR(3),
>   `qty` INTEGER,
>   `previous_id` VARCHAR(18)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO order_product   (order_id, price, model, qty, previous_id) 
> VALUES   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1807', '1,200', 'CBL', '1', 1788)
> ,   ('1806', '1,200', 'CBL', '1', 1788)
> ,   ('1899', '1,200', 'CBL', '1', 1788)
> ,   ('1809', '1,200', 'SPL', '1', 1788);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `order_id`, `price`, `model`, `qty`, `previous_id`
> FROM
> (SELECT 
> `order_id`, `price`, `model`, `qty`, `previous_id`
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY `model` ORDER BY `qty` DESC) rn
> ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_product WHERE `model` = o1.`model` AND `qty` <> -1) mx
> ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_product WHERE `model` = o1.`model` AND `qty` = -1) nx
> FROM order_product o1
> WHERE `order_id` = '1788' OR `previous_id` = '1788') t1
> WHERE rn <= IF(mx = 0 , nx,mx+ IF(nx=0, 0,nx -mx))
> ```
>
> ```
> order_id | price | model | qty | previous_id
> -------: | :---- | :---- | --: | :----------
>     1807 | 1,200 | CBL   |   1 | 1788       
>     1806 | 1,200 | CBL   |   1 | 1788       
>     1899 | 1,200 | CBL   |   1 | 1788       
>     1788 | 1,200 | CBL   |  -1 | null       
>     1788 | 1,200 | CBL   |  -1 | null       
>     1788 | 1,200 | CBL   |  -1 | null       
>     1809 | 1,200 | SPL   |   1 | 1788
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=15c30c82b0c7232bc10392e91bde6b4a)*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE order_product (
>   `order_id` INTEGER,
>   `price` VARCHAR(5),
>   `model` VARCHAR(3),
>   `qty` INTEGER,
>   `previous_id` VARCHAR(18)
> );
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO order_product   (order_id, price, model, qty, previous_id) 
> VALUES   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null)
> ,   ('1807', '1,200', 'CBL', '1', 1788)
> ,   ('1806', '1,200', 'CBL', '1', 1788)
> ,   ('1899', '1,200', 'CBL', '1', 1788)
> ,   ('1809', '1,200', 'SPL', '1', 1788);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `order_id`, `price`, `model`, `qty`, `previous_id`
> FROM
> (SELECT 
> `order_id`, `price`, `model`, `qty`, `previous_id`
> , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY `model` ORDER BY `qty` DESC) rn
> ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_product WHERE  `qty` <> -1) mx
> ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_product WHERE `model` = o1.`model` AND `qty` <> -1) mx1
> ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_product WHERE `model` = o1.`model` AND `qty` = -1) nx
> FROM order_product o1
> WHERE `order_id` = '1788' OR `previous_id` = '1788') t1
> WHERE rn <= IF(mx = 0 , nx,mx1+ IF(nx=0, 0,nx -mx))
> ```
>
> ```
> order_id | price | model | qty | previous_id
> -------: | :---- | :---- | --: | :----------
>     1807 | 1,200 | CBL   |   1 | 1788       
>     1806 | 1,200 | CBL   |   1 | 1788       
>     1899 | 1,200 | CBL   |   1 | 1788       
>     1788 | 1,200 | CBL   |  -1 | null       
>     1788 | 1,200 | CBL   |  -1 | null       
>     1809 | 1,200 | SPL   |   1 | 1788
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=473d2490a462b01f366e4276084f09b8)*

Comment: Your example has really helped but it will only work if all model codes are different. However, if some models are exactly the same, this no longer works. For example if 3 of the model codes are SBB, it will not display all 4 rows. @nbk

Comment: if you have new requirements accept and upvote the answer and make a new question. i added a new query

Comment: the example works but It's not consistent @nbk.
`INSERT INTO order_product
  (order_id, price, model, qty, previous_id)
VALUES
  ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null),
  ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null),
  ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null),
  ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null),
  ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null),
  ('1788', '1,200', 'CBL', '-1', Null),
  ('1807', '1,200', 'CBL', '1', 1788),
  ('1806', '1,200', 'CBL', '1', 1788),
  ('1899', '1,200', 'CBL', '1', 1788),
  ('1809', '1,200', 'SPL', '1', 1788);`

Comment: Notice that I have 6 on backorder but only 4 were filled which should show 7 rows but your example still shows 4 @nbk

Comment: as i already said more patterns more code

Comment: this one looks promising. I will try and upvote @nbk.

Comment: as long there is a programmable pattern you can achieve everything, but it gets more and more complicated as you need more and more columns to get the correct numbers. You should gige it a try sometimes

Comment: for some reason it works fine with db <> fiddle but when I try through mysql database, it gives me an extra row with a backorder. I don't know why. I did give you an upvote because it does work with the db <> fiddle @nbk.

Comment: A backorder? Can you add it to the fiddle

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with your previous code. Apparently why it wasn't working exactly as intended was because I had different orders with the similar items. Therefore your previous code is working for me. I just added order_id = 1788 to (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_product WHERE  order_id = 1788 and `model` = o1.`model` AND `qty` <> -1) mx,
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_product WHERE order_id = 1788 and `model` = o1.`model` AND `qty` = -1) nx @nbk

Comment: Code in comments are horrible but I am glad you got your result

Comment: Thanks for your help. Without your help, I wouldn't have figured out how it's done. @nbk :)